# Thruk - Get details using API

Tags: nagios, thruk

I want to know the possibility of getting the details which is listed in thruk interface using API calls.

For example, I need to collect details which is listed under Host Groups --> Summary(Grid) tab using python script, I need to know whether any API available for collecting those details. or any other means which will help me to collect those details in automated way ?

Update:
I can see API link here: https://www.thruk.org/documentation/rest.html, But for me http://your_webserver/thruk/r/ is not working, whether any plugin need to be installed ? Please advice

Answer (score 1):

The rest API is included and automatically enabled since release 2.24. Make sure you have at least that version installed.

```
2.24     Fri Oct 26 18:40:37 CEST 2018
          - add rest api
```